# Modules with different Scopes

Tags: android, dagger-2

How do I make a Module which has an annotation, like @UserScope, dependent on another Module that's a @Singleton?

```
@Module(includes = {ApplicationModule.class})
public class JobManagerModule
{
    private static final String TAG = JobManagerModule.class.getSimpleName();

    @UserScope
    @Provides
    public JobManager providesJobManager(final Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Providing JobManager");
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder(context).build();
        return new JobManager(configuration);
    }
}
```

Here, JobManagerModule provides using @UserScope but the ApplicationModule provides the Context object (which JobManagerModule needs) as a @Singleton.

This shows errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a different `Scope`, then this scope must be a subcomponent of `@Singleton`.

Suppose you have `ApplicationComponent` annotated with `@Singleton`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = ApplicationModule.class
)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    JobManagerComponent provide(JobManagerModule jobManagerModule);
}
```

`ApplicationModule` provides `Context`:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    protected final Application mApplication;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    public Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

Notice, that `ApplicationComponent` must provide `JobManagerComponent`
 and `Context` is provided with `@ApplicationContext` annotation.

Now you create `JobManagerComponent` as a `@Subcomponent` of `ApplicationComponent`:

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(
        modules = JobManagerModule.class
)
public interface JobManagerComponent{
}
```

`JobManagerModule`:

```
@Module
public class JobManagerModule
{
    private static final String TAG = JobManagerModule.class.getSimpleName();

    @UserScope
    @Provides
    public JobManager providesJobManager(@ApplicationContext Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Providing JobManager");
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder(context).build();
        return new JobManager(configuration);
    }
}
```

Notice the removal of `include` from `@Module` annotation and `Context` annotated with `@ApplicationContext`

Creation of `JobManagerComponent`:

```
JobManagerComponent jobComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
    .applicationModule(applicationModule)
    .build()
    .provide(new JobManagerModule());
```

Comment: This has solved the issue but it's caused a conflict somewhere else. I'll post another question.

Comment: I've asked the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632408/two-injects-in-one-object-but-from-two-different-components

Comment: Any idea how I can inject the JobManager in to an MyObject along with a different object from a different component?