# Two @Injects in one object but from two different Components

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have:

```
@Inject
AdalService adalService;

@Inject
Realm realm;
```

Both of these come from two different Components.

**AdalComponent**

```
@UserScope
@Component(dependencies = {NetComponent.class}, modules = AdalServiceModule.class)
public interface AdalServiceComponent
{
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    void inject(EventsJob eventsJob);
}
```

**RealmComponent**

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(modules = RealmModule.class)
public interface RealmComponent
{
    void inject(EventsJob eventsJob);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error:(16, 10) error: io.realm.Realm cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
    io.realm.Realm is injected at
    com.bjss.bjssevents.jobs.EventsJob.realm
    com.bjss.bjssevents.jobs.EventsJob is injected at
    com.bjss.bjssevents.dagger.components.AdalServiceComponent.inject(eventsJob)
```

**RealmModule**

```
@Module
public class RealmModule
{
    private static final String TAG = RealmModule.class.getSimpleName();

    public RealmModule(@Singleton final Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Configuring Realm");
        Realm.init(context);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build());
    }

    @UserScope
    @Provides
    public Realm providesRealm()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Providing Realm");
        return Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem themes not in shown code. It should be in the method, which `@Provides` `Realm`

Comment: Where is your `@Module` for providing the Realm instance? Can you paste that code also.

Comment: Added the RealmModule.

Comment: @raxelsson any ideas?

Comment: not from the top of my head, sorry. Thinking of what it could be. Error indicated that it was missing your `@Provides` method.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Any ideas?

Comment: Add the RealmModule to your AdalComponent

Answer (score 2):

Inside `AdalServiceComponent` and `RealmComponent` you have the same method:

```
void inject(EventsJob eventsJob);
```

That is unacceptable. The must be only one `inject` method for specified object (argument of `inject` method).

Also you can't inject things from two moduled at the same level. Both `Component`'s are annotated with the same Scope: `@UserScope`. They don't know nothing about each other. If you want to define resources in `AdalServiceComponent` and `RealmComponent` make one of them parent `Component` and the other one `Subcomponent`. And the `inject` method should be in subcomponent.

Please read [this excellent article series](http://frogermcs.github.io/) about advanced Dagger-2 behaviour to gain better understanding of this library.

Comment: +1 as that makes some sense. I've since fixed the issue by having just one component and adding ALL modules to it.